# Javascript Facebook Connect in ROR website

Tags: javascript, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a ruby-on-rails web application in which I want to integrate "Facebook connect" functionality so as to share different activities in the Facebook. How can I do that using Javascript? Please suggest me some demo links.

Also, If a user connects his/her account with Facebook by clicking on "Facebook Connect" button, then logs out of my website and then again that user logs in to my website, his/her account should still be connected. So, how to remember such user settings across the sessions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this tutorial for facebook connect

http://udooz.net/blog/2011/02/facebook-app-using-rails-koala/